# Unable to disable RecognizesAccessKey property for ComboBox dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF window with a ComboBox and have come across the dreaded access key issue. Through my google-fu I've discovered that I can turn it off with the following code;

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="RecognizesAccessKey" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

This works relatively well, when an item is selected, it now shows the underscores and I don't need to worry about any `.Replace(...)` calls in the code behind. The problem is that it only works for the selected item, all the other items have the underscore hidden.

In the below picture, I selected `AU-15003\SQLEXPRESS_2014` (originally the underscore was hidden), the underscore was shown when the dropdown closed. Then I re-opened the dropdown and the underscore stayed for that item. The other items still have no underscore (SQLEXPRESS2008 follows the same pattern).

I'm not sure why this is, I can't seem to find any other places where I could turn the RecognizesAccessKey property off.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but I can surely tell you why implicit styles targeting `ContentPresenter` tend not to work as expected.

The rule is that templates (`ControlTemplates` as well as `DataTemplates`) are boundaries for applying implicit styles, i.e. implicit style defined outside of the template will not be applied to elements inside one. There's one exception to that rule - if the targeted type derives from `Control`, the style will be applied even inside the templates. And you can easily check that `ContentPresenter` does not derive from `Control`. Moreover, the `ContentPresenter` in question (the one displaying the item in the `ComboBox` drop-down) is "located" in `ComboBoxItem`'s template.

Now I cannot make out anything specific enough to reproduce your issue from the code you've posted, but I can advise you on how to tweak the `ContentPresenter` in the `ComboBox` drop-down - your best bet is to supply custom `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox (...)>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If you'd like more general solution (one that resembles your attempt), you could create an implicit style targeting `ComboBox` and setting `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` property in a similar manner:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" RecognizesAccessKey="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: Ah, the perils of google-fu. That'll teach me to look into the why rather than just fix it. Your first solution worked well for me. I've got some custom styling via material design and the second generic solution stripped the styling.